# Changing button text with button click not working

Tags: python, button, tkinter, minesweeper

I am programming Minesweeper. I have completed all of the logic and now I am just doing the GUI. I am using Tkinter. With so many spaces on the board, I want to automate the creating of all these buttons, which I have done this way:

```
button_list = []

def create_buttons():
    # Create the buttons
    for x in range(code_squares):
        # Code_squares is how many squares are on the board
        new_button = Button(frame_list[x], text = "", relief = RAISED)
        new_button.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        new_button.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event: box_open(event, x))
        button_list.append(new_button)

def box_open(event, x):
    if box_list[x] == "M":
        # Checks if the block is a mine
        button_list[x].config(text="M", relief = SUNKEN)
        # Stops if it was a mine
        root.quit()
    else:
        # If not a mine, it changes the button text to the xth term in box_list, which is the amount of nearby mines.
        print("in")
        button_list[x].config(text=box_list[x], relief = SUNKEN)
```

The print statement is just a test. When I click a spot, it will execute the print statement, so I know its getting there, but it will not change the button text. All help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is the way you're trying to embed `x` in your `lambda`, give this a try instead to see if it solves your problem:

```
from functools import partial

def create_buttons():
    for n in range(code_squares):
        # Code_squares is how many squares are on the board
        new_button = Button(frame_list[n], text="", relief=RAISED)
        new_button.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        new_button.bind("<Button-1>", partial(box_open, x=n))
        button_list.append(new_button)

def box_open(event, x):
    if box_list[x] == "M":
        # Checks if the block is a mine
        button_list[x].config(text="M", relief=SUNKEN)
        # Stops if it was a mine
        root.quit()
    else:
        # If not a mine, it changes the button text to the xth
        # term in box_list, which is the amount of nearby mines.
        button_list[x].config(text=box_list[x], relief=SUNKEN)

button_list = []
```

Comment: That fixed it thanks! Just for future reference do you think you could explain what exactly the problem was?

Comment: I'm on thin ice here but I believe you expected `x` to be valid inside the `lambda` in a closure sense but that wasn't the case.  Some folks might have gone with the simpler `lambda event, n=x: ...` approach but I went with `partial` after having been chided about the other (perhaps a quirk of syntax vs. a formal approach, I dunno.)